# Display style in text, but at text style size

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts, displaystyle

I would like to write `$\sum_i$` to be displayed as `\displaystyle $\sum_i$` but at the size of `$\sum_i$`. How can I do that?

I could maybe use a subscript command, but that is not my question. My question is more generic about the display style within the text style at the size of the text style.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. You could see the **related** at the right of this page. Probabily canyou resolve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\limits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
abc $\sum_i$ $\sum\limits_i$ def
\end{document}
```

[image: limits]